# undefined reference not appearing disassembly for objdump

Tags: bash, objdump

I'm trying to solve a linker error on some third party code.  I have the following:

```
/builddir/obj.o: undefined reference to foo
```

If I do an objdump on obj.o, `foo` does not show up in the disassembly, but it does show up as an undefined object:

```
> objdump -S /builddir/obj.o | grep foo
> objdump -t /builddir/obj.o | grep foo
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 foo
```

So what would cause a symbol to me marked as undefined when there is no reference to it in the disassembly?

Note: obj.o was not stripped, and shows other symbols